# How to deploy a multi project solution of visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, iis, web-deployment, webdeploy

i have some problems to deploy a multi project (4 projects) solution to iis 7, by  using Web Deploy.

In practice, the entire solution works fine debugging it into vs2012.

Then, I packaged the main project (only the main project!!!) with vs2012, then deployed it into my local iis by the IIS Web Deploy.

When i open the main web page, it shows me an error, a reference or an assembly of one of the other project  is missing!

Where am i wrong? Is that the right way to deploy a multi project solution?

Comment: Nobody can help you if you don't give enough information. What are the other projects in the solution?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply!! There are 2 web project, 1 class library, and a WPF... C#

Comment: You should be able to just deploy the second web project. What do you want done with the WPF project.

Comment: For every class library they need to be a reference to the web projects.  For every web project you will need to deploy them independently of each other for all the items to get deployed.